# is this the right way to initialize a semaphore with two threads

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I am new using the concept of semaphores. What I am trying to do is to integrate a sender and a receiver into a single project such that if I run the project both sender and receiver exchange the data simultaneously. Below is what I tried but my Eclipse CDT IDE is showing an
`**error: ‘receiver’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pthread_create(mythread2, NULL, (void*)receiver, NULL);**`

Any help Appreciated.

```
sem_t semaphore;

void sender() {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait( & semaphore);
        printf("Hello from the sender!\n");
        sleep(1); /* do not run so fast! */
        /* Write any number of messages, re-using the existing string-buffer: no leak!!. */
        for (i = 1; i <= NUM_MSG; i++) {
            msg - > index = i;
            snprintf(msg - > content, MAX_MSG_LEN, "Message no. %d", msg - > index);
            printf("Writing message: %s\n", msg - > content);
            status = Chat_ChatMessageDataWriter_write(talker, msg, userHandle);
            checkStatus(status, "Chat_ChatMessageDataWriter_write");
            sleep(1); /* do not run so fast! */
        }
        sem_post( & semaphore);
        printf("hello before exit\n");
        //        pthread_exit(NULL);
        printf("hello  after exit\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    void receiver() {
        while (0) {
            sem_wait( & semaphore);
            printf("Hello from the receiver!\n");
            while (!terminated) {

                status = Chat_ChatMessageDataReader_take(
                    chatAdmin,
                    msgSeq,
                    infoSeq,
                    DDS_LENGTH_UNLIMITED,
                    DDS_ANY_SAMPLE_STATE,
                    DDS_ANY_VIEW_STATE,
                    DDS_ALIVE_INSTANCE_STATE);

                checkStatus(status, "Chat_NamedMessageDataReader_take");

                for (i = 0; i < msgSeq - > _length; i++) {
                    Chat_ChatMessage * msg = & (msgSeq - > _buffer[i]);
                    printf("%s\n", msg - > content);
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
            }
            sem_post( & semaphore);

            status = Chat_ChatMessageDataReader_return_loan(chatAdmin, msgSeq, infoSeq);
            checkStatus(status, "Chat_ChatMessageDataReader_return_loan");

            /* Sleep for some amount of time, as not to consume too much CPU cycles. */
#ifdef USE_NANOSLEEP
            sleeptime.tv_sec = 0;
            sleeptime.tv_nsec = 100000000;
            nanosleep( & sleeptime, & remtime);
#elif defined _WIN32
            Sleep(100);
#else
            usleep(1000000);
#endif
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

    /* Use the changed policy when defining the ChatMessage topic */
    chatMessageTopic = DDS_DomainParticipant_create_topic(
        participant,
        "Chat_ChatMessage",
        chatMessageTypeName,
        history_topic_qos,
        NULL,
        DDS_STATUS_MASK_NONE);
    checkHandle(chatMessageTopic, "DDS_DomainParticipant_create_topic (ChatMessage)");

    /* Create a Publisher for the chatter application. */
    chatPublisher = DDS_DomainParticipant_create_publisher(participant, pub_qos, NULL, DDS_STATUS_MASK_NONE);
    checkHandle(chatPublisher, "DDS_DomainParticipant_create_publisher");

    /* Create a DataWriter for the ChatMessage Topic (using the appropriate QoS). */
    talker = DDS_Publisher_create_datawriter(
        chatPublisher,
        chatMessageTopic,
        DDS_DATAWRITER_QOS_USE_TOPIC_QOS,
        NULL,
        DDS_STATUS_MASK_NONE);
    checkHandle(talker, "DDS_Publisher_create_datawriter (chatMessage)");

    /* Initialize the chat messages on Heap. */
    msg = Chat_ChatMessage__alloc();
    checkHandle(msg, "Chat_ChatMessage__alloc");
    msg - > userID = ownID;
    msg - > index = 0;
    msg - > content = DDS_string_alloc(MAX_MSG_LEN);
    checkHandle(msg - > content, "DDS_string_alloc");

    snprintf(msg - > content, MAX_MSG_LEN, "Hi there, I will send you %d more messages.", NUM_MSG);

    printf("Writing message: %s\n", msg - > content);

    /* Register a chat message for this user (pre-allocating resources for it!!) */
    userHandle = DDS__FooDataWriter_register_instance(talker, msg);

    /* Write a message using the pre-generated instance handle. */
    status = DDS__FooDataWriter_write(talker, msg, userHandle);
    checkStatus(status, "Chat_ChatMessageDataWriter_write");
    /* Create a Subscriber for the MessageBoard application. */
    chatSubscriber = DDS_DomainParticipant_create_subscriber(participant, sub_qos, NULL, DDS_STATUS_MASK_NONE);
    checkHandle(chatSubscriber, "DDS_DomainParticipant_create_subscriber");
    /* Create a DataReader for the chatMessageTopic Topic (using the appropriate QoS). */
    chatAdmin = DDS_Subscriber_create_datareader(
        chatSubscriber,
        chatMessageTopic,
        DDS_DATAREADER_QOS_USE_TOPIC_QOS,
        NULL,
        DDS_STATUS_MASK_NONE);
    checkHandle(chatAdmin, "DDS_Subscriber_create_datareader");

    /* Print a message that the MessageBoard has opened. */
    printf("MessageBoard has opened: send ChatMessages \n\n");

    /* Allocate the sequence holders for the DataReader */
    msgSeq = DDS_sequence_Chat_ChatMessage__alloc();
    checkHandle(msgSeq, "DDS_sequence_Chat_NamedMessage__alloc");
    infoSeq = DDS_SampleInfoSeq__alloc();
    checkHandle(infoSeq, "DDS_SampleInfoSeq__alloc");

    //initializing the semaphore
    sem_init( & semaphore, 0, 1);
    pthread_t * mythread1;
    pthread_t * mythread2;
    mythread1 = (pthread_t * ) malloc(sizeof( * mythread1));
    mythread2 = (pthread_t * ) malloc(sizeof( * mythread2));
    //start the thread
    printf("Starting thread, semaphore is unlocked.\n");
    pthread_create(mythread1, NULL, (void * ) sender, NULL);
    pthread_create(mythread2, NULL, (void * ) receiver, NULL);
    getchar();
    sem_wait( & semaphore);
    printf("Semaphore locked.\n");
    getchar();
    printf("Semaphore Unlocked.\n");
    sem_post( & semaphore);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. How do you expect us to help you if you don't post your *actual code*?

Comment: @EOF Please take a look at the complete code

Comment: Missing headers, still doesn't compile.

Comment: you cant compile the code, for that you have to install DDS on your machine. All I need to know is if we can initialize and use the semaphores in this way. That's the reason why I posted simple code first.

Comment: the error starts here
 pthread_create(mythread2, NULL, (void*)receiver, NULL);
while initializing the semaphores

Comment: The compiler error you've posted has nothing to do with semaphores. I'd recommend you create a *minimal* example of your program that you can post here in its entirety.

Comment: okay let me put this straight. I have created two threads mthread1 and mythread 2, if you could scroll down a bit. All I want to know is if I can create pthreads as if I did in the above program

Comment: haha that is what I tried to show you previously where I created a semaphore and initialized , created threads and used a printf  function

Comment: You obviously *cannot* create threads the way you tried. Your compiler told you you cannot, and they tend to know these things quite well. I'd recommend you start with a beginner's tutorial on C, learn about undefined behavior and try again.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion@EOF

Comment: I wonder why you want to use a semaphore in the first place. It looks like you are trying to synchronize the `DataWriter` and `DataReader` activities, but the DDS API already has support for that. Check out the WaitSet functionality in the spec, or see [this documentation](http://community.rti.com/rti-doc/510/ndds/doc/html/api_c/group__DDSConditionsModule.html#gaffdc85b9ca97eb432a2c17c52bc00f82)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a closing brace '}' at the end of function 'sender'.   This should address your specific error "‘receiver’ undeclared".

[Also, the "while(0) { ... }" construct in function 'receiver' is questionable...]

While I am answering, please allow me to suggest the following:

1) The issue of locking/synchronization (semaphores, in this example) is orthogonal to DDS (or any other data communication mechanism). [You will probably have much more success if you can keep the code clean and focused when asking for help on a forum like this.]

2) Some implementations of DDS (I can speak specifically only for CoreDX DDS) are thread-safe, and so do not require protection around the API calls. [You may want to check with the specific DDS vendor to confirm this.] From this example, it is difficult for me to infer if your application logic requires the locking, but it doesn't appear that it does.